# Call WCF service without .svc file name

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any setting that can allow me to access the WCF service instead of using

```
http://192.168.0.28/SampleArticle/RestService.svc/authorize
```

change to

```
http://192.168.0.28/SampleArticle/authorize
```

without added the RestService.svc reference name in the URL.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [serviceActivations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530411/how-can-i-host-a-wcf-service-without-an-svc-file-in-iis) element in web.config?

Comment: You can use another hosting environments like Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use URL Rewrite Module of IIS. You may refer the MSDN [blog]: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2008/08/22/rest-in-wcf-part-ix-controlling-the-uri/ .

Updated:
You may try something below to replace the entire RestService.svc from the URL.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RemoveRestService" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/(RestService.svc)/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: but i not wan to remove the extension .svc , is without showing the RestService.svc in the url when passing. Its should be different right ?

Comment: You may just need to design the URL rewrite scripts in such a way that the whole RestService.svc is being removed. I updated the answer although i have not tested yet but it should work.